# How to split a column into two in R based on a symbol from scraping result?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

So I scraped IMDB website using `rvest` and encountered some splitting issue. I have tried different methods to split the column but all failed.

This is my code for scraping the information from IMDB website:

`votes_gross <- pagesource %>% html_nodes(".sort-num_votes-visible") %>% html_text()`

Then I used the following codes to clean and split:

```
votes_gross <- gsub("\r?\n|\r", " ", votes_gross)
votes_gross <- data.frame(votes_gross)
library(tidyr)
votes_gross <- separate(votes_gross,
       col = "votes_gross",
       into = c("Votes", "Gross"),
       sep = "|")
```

the data frame become empty right after I execute the separate codes. I also tried using `strsplit` but failed as well. I know there are other similar questions on here, but they don't seem to be similar to my situation.

I'm hoping to make these:

```
          votes_gross
Votes: 489,547 | Gross: $700.06M
Votes: 615,401 | Gross: $678.82M
Votes: 192,034 | Gross: $608.58M
```

into these:

```
    Votes         Gross (Millions)
Votes: 489,547    Gross: $700.06
Votes: 615,401    Gross: $678.82
Votes: 192,034    Gross: $608.58
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?separate`

> sep -  If character, is interpreted as a regular expression. The default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values.

So, if we need it to evaluate literally, place it inside square brackets (`[|]` or escape `\\|`) or else it is regarded as `OR`

```
library(tidyverse)
votes_gross <- separate(votes_gross,
   col = "votes_gross",
   into = c("Votes", "Gross"),
   sep = "\\s*[|]\\s*")
```

Comment: I see, it worked perfectly. Thank you for mentioning it, I forgot it's a regular expression.